# React Native proportional scaling of square image

Tags: react-native, styling

I have a `view` that spans 100% of its parent and inside I have a square `image` that needs to span 100% of that `view` and keep its aspect ratio without cropping. How can I accomplish this without absolute dimensions?

Here is a mock up reference image of what I want to do:

[image: reference]

Answer (score 4):

Okay figured it out, you need to have a view around your image.

```
<View style={{ aspectRatio: 1 }}>
  <Image resizeMode="cover" style={{ aspectRatio: 1, height: 100 }} />
<View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `resizeMode` on the `Image` tag. Some of the options maintain aspect ratio (`cover`, `contain`).

Comment: This works, but then my image fills the entire container's height too which I don't want because I need it to float to the top.

Comment: You probably want `contain` and not `cover` then?

Answer (score 1):

Use ***flex:1*** in your style.

```
<View style={styles.canvasContainer}>
  <Image
    resizeMode="contain"
    source={{uri: 'http://abc.def.com/hij.jpg'}}
    style={styles.canvas} />
</View>

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    canvasContainer: {
      flex:1,
      alignItems: 'stretch'
    },
    canvas: {
        flex:1          //This is what you want!
       // width: 200, 
       // height: 200
}});
```

Live Demo: https://snack.expo.io/@xystudio/fullsizeimage
Snapshot:
[image]

Comment: This works, but then my image fills the entire container's height too which I don't want because I need it to float to the top.